# ASP.NET Core YARP Reverse Proxy multiple listen ports

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kestrel-http-server, ms-yarp

I want to Reverse Proxy multiple ports, with YARP.

```
0.0.0.0:5001  =>  RemoteHost.com:7001
0.0.0.0:5002  =>  RemoteHost.com:7002
0.0.0.0:5003  =>  RemoteHost.com:7003
0.0.0.0:5004  =>  RemoteHost.com:7004
```

All the examples seem to map URLs, and not ports.

```
public class ProxyConfigProvider : IProxyConfigProvider
{

var routeConfig = new RouteConfig
{
       RouteId = "route1",
       ClusterId = "cluster1",
       Match = new RouteMatch
       {
           Path = "/api/service1/{**catch-all}"
       }
};

var clusterConfig = new ClusterConfig
  {
      Destinations = new [] = {"Address": "https://RemoteHost.com:7001"}
....
```

How do you set up Kestrel and YARP to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can route by port using the Hosts field

```
"Match": {
  "Hosts" : [ "*:5001" ]
```

You also need to tell kestrel to listen on those ports.